# send array from c++ application to webApplication

Tags: c++, websocket, ubuntu-14.04

i want to send one array from my Desktop application (c++) to another Web application(browser-based) which is written in javascript. 
What is the standard approach to do this ?
my purpose just is to try send array through websocket to a simple web application.
i am a little familiar with node.js but i dont know is it possible to use it inside c++ application or not.

Comment: What do you mean by "send"? Are the two programs on the same machine? Different machines that connect through a network? Do you know anything about [inter-process communication (IPC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) or network-programming? Perhaps you should start there?

Comment: there are in same machine,i am not sure about ipc is a good approach in my case or not ,I think network-programming maybe better for me

Comment: @Unix2000: please **edit your question** to improve it, but don't comment it

Comment: You first need to understand HTTP (and how Websockets are built above HTTP). Then you should improve your question

Answer (score 0):

> I want to send one array from my Desktop application (c++) to another Web application(browser-based) which is written in javascript. What is the standard approach to do this ?

Your question is too broad, or shows some misconceptions about desktop applications and web applications.

Be sure to **understand** (in details) **[HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)** and **reason in [terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) of HTTP requests and responses** (including those initiating a websocket connection). Remember that a websocket is above some HTTP connection.... Understand the role of [HTTP cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie).

---

You could change your desktop application into a web application (perhaps running on `http://localhost/` ...), but that requires some significant work and redesign. You probably then want to use some HTTP server library, like [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) or [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) (it supports [Websockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)).

Perhaps you might improve your web application to make [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) requests (e.g. to some `http://localhost:34567` ...) to you local application transformed into a specialized web sever running locally (and also using websockets, if you need that).

Perhaps you want your Desktop application to also become an HTTP client. You then need some HTTP client library (like [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) or [QtNetwork](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-programming.html)).

Comment: he specifically mentioned websockets, I don't think HTTP libs will help him with that

Comment: `libonion` has some websocket support. I even contributed to it